# Response on RestSharp with wrong charset(probably)

Tags: c#, encoding, restsharp

I have a server response, on a RestSharp client, and if i grab the response on PostMan it comes good:
 Example: instalação
But when i call try this response on the RestSharp Client it comes like this:
 Example: instala��o

the code:
{

```
 var requestatt = new RestRequest("/mge/service.sbr?serviceName=CRUDServiceProvider.loadView", Method.POST);
          // requestsharp.AddXmlBody(stringrequest);
          requestatt.AddParameter("text/xml", bodyrequestatt, ParameterType.RequestBody);
          requestatt.AddHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml;charset=ISO-8859-1");
          IRestResponse responseatt = new RestResponse();
          responseatt.ContentEncoding = "ISO-8859-1";
          responseatt = client.Execute(requestatt);
```

}

Comment: Check the encoding headers in Postman, are you sure you need `ISO-8859-1`?